# ActiveRecord/SQL select all ModalA where no instances of an associated ModelB (if present) belong to ModelC

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a rather sophisticated query using ActiveRecord (though I'm open to using raw SQL if it's more easier) and need some help refining it.

I have the following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts
    has_many :workplace_stories
end

class WorkplaceStory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :questions
    has_many :invites
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :workplace_story
    belongs_to :contact
    has_one :response
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invite
    has_many :answers
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :invites
end
```

I want to write a query that will select all workplace stories that do not have any invites belonging to a given contact where the invite has a response. In other words, given the following:

```
company = Company.last
=> #<Company:0x007fef5f58bd98>
contact = company.contact.last
=> #<Contact:0x007fef5f58bd98>
contact.invites.count
=> 1
contact.invites.first.response
=> #<Response:0x007fef5f58bd98>
company.workplace_stories.count
=> 5
company.workplace_stories.map { |x| x.invites.count }
=> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
```

I wan't to write a query, something like what I have below, that will return all the workplace stories where none of the invites with a response (if there are any) belong to `contact`. The query below is close to what I'm aiming for, but it only selects stories that have at least one invite - in this case, there are two.

```
stories = workplace_stories.joins(:invites).where.not(invites: {contact: contact}).order(updated_at: :desc).uniq.count
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For queries like this I like to get it working in SQL first, then decide how to express it in ActiveRecord. It looks like this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    workplace_stories wps
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1
                    FROM    invites i
                    INNER JOIN  responses r
                    ON      r.invite_id = i.id
                    WHERE   i.contact_id = ?
                    AND     i.workplace_story_id = wps.id)
```

Personally for this kind of thing I like to write a scope, which makes it easy to reuse and easy to combine with other conditions:

```
class WorkplaceStory

  scope :without_response_by, -> (contact_id) {
    where(<<-EOQ, contact_id)
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1
                  FROM    invites i
                  INNER JOIN  responses r
                  ON      r.invite_id = i.id
                  WHERE   i.contact_id = ?
                  AND     i.workplace_story_id = workplace_stories.id)
    EOQ
  }

  # ...
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm tempted to try an implement this with ActiveRecord, but looking at the SQL, it is more clear how the query works, so I think I'll stick with a scope on the model. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Btw, make sure you have indexes on the relevant foreign key columns or this query will get slow!